# Weirdly unrelated job ads

Tags: support, jobs

While I'm somewhat interested in job ads in SO, I can't remember seeing one that was related to my interests.

I'm aware that in my main interest topics Dart, Dart Angular,and Flutter there aren't many job offers yet,
but almost all ads I get shown are about Java and React, topics I'm not involved in any way. There are also very popular areas like Angular (TS) where I'm very active (#1 top user) but not even here I get related ads.

Is there anything I can do do get more relevant ads or none at all if there are no relevant ads.

A way to dismiss ads I'm not interested in would be great.
When I get the same ads I'm not the least bit interested in shown for weeks, the job ads become so useless distraction that the only useful thing to do is to block them.

I can't imagine this being the intention of the SO team.

I also updated my jobs profile a few times with no noticable effect.

Comment: What is the "TS" abbreviation?

Comment: @PeterMortensen TypeScript

Comment: If you hover over the ad, you should see a little "x" in the upper right corner that will allow you to dismiss/hide ads you're not interested in

Comment: Example: https://i.imgur.com/43Ru1XC.png

Comment: @rossipedia thanks, I looked for a way to dismiss it but didn't see that.